# How can I identify rectangles in an image when they are of different colours, outlines and sometimes very close to the background colour

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to extract rectangles from an image. These are digital stickies on a digital notepad. They can be any user configurable colour, including transparent with a border. I want to be able to input a jpg/png file and get back a list of each of the rectangles, their coordinates and the colour of the rectangle.

OpenCV with Python is the route that I want to use for this. Below is the example image, the intention is to detect all of the rectangles only and retrieve the above mentioned information.

[image: Example Image for Extraction]

I've done quite a lot of reading and been using the find contours method to try and achieve my goal however I'm not getting the desired result.

```
import cv2

# reading image
img = cv2.imread('images/example_shapes.jpg')

# converting image into grayscale image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# setting threshold of gray image
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# using a findContours() function
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
    threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

i = 0

# list for storing names of shapes
for contour in contours:

    # here we are ignoring first counter because
    # findcontour function detects whole image as shape
    if i == 0:
        i = 1
        continue

    # cv2.approxPloyDP() function to approximate the shape
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(
        contour, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)

# displaying the image after drawing contours
# img = cv2.resize(img, (500, 500))
cv2.imshow('shapes', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This would only detect the 2 rectangles in the middle and gave the following:
[image]

I had then attempted to adjust the threshold to be adaptive thresholding:

```
threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 7)
```

which produced the following result
[image]

Neither approach seems to be able to detect the rectangles who are close together and also a close colour to the backround and neither detects the rectangles with a stroke. The adaptive thresholding also returns a lot of items that are irrelevant.

Any suggestions on how to approach would be very welcome!

Comment: Are all rectangles either in the background or completely inside another rectangle? In other words: are rectangles always surrounded everywhere by the same color as in the picture?

Comment: What app created these stickies? If it's written by you, you could consider embedding the rectangles' coordinates in the image.

Comment: @Elerium115 rectangles can only be inside another rectangle OR inside the broader background. It's not possible to have a possible overlap.

Comment: @MarkSetchell not an app that I have the code for unfortunately.

Comment: Try detecting the unique colors, and remapping to equidistant colors, so there is more difference between background and close to background. Also try working with the color channels separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This has been a task that requires one thing above all - perseverance (which might explain the few downvotes you got on your question).**

So to teach you how to fish. Everything has been about hyperparamter tuning and visualization - a lot of it. Basically after each step like so:

```
# Visualize edges
cv2.imshow("Edges", cv2.resize(edges, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then going stepwise. Happy with the thresholding - yes, next. Happy with the edge detection - yes, next. You get my point. This you can only do with recurrent visualization in each step.

**So this is what you get with this code**

[[image: And this is how the result looks like1]

**This is the full function:**

```
def find_rectangles(image):
        
    # Visualize original image
    # cv2.imshow("Original Image", cv2.resize(image, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    # cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # This gets rid of the background gray lines.
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)

    # # Visualize thresholded image
    # cv2.imshow("Thresholded Image", cv2.resize(binary, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    # cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    # Find edges using Canny edge detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(binary, 50, 150)

    # Visualize edges
    cv2.imshow("Edges", cv2.resize(edges, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Find lines using probabilistic Hough Transform
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=25, minLineLength=1, maxLineGap=15)

    # Create an empty mask to draw lines
    mask = np.zeros_like(gray)

    # Draw lines on the mask
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        cv2.line(mask, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 255, 2)

    # Visualize Hough lines
    cv2.imshow("Hough Lines", cv2.resize(mask, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Apply morphological operations to enhance rectangles
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    dilated_mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=6)
    eroded_mask = cv2.erode(dilated_mask, kernel, iterations=5)

    # Visualize enhanced mask
    cv2.imshow("Enhanced Mask", cv2.resize(eroded_mask, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Find contours in the mask
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(eroded_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1)

    # Filter contours by shape
    rectangles = []
    for contour in contours:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            # Get the bounding box of the contour
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            rectangles.append({
                "x": x,
                "y": y,
                "w": w,
                "h": h,
                "color": cv2.mean(image[y:y + h, x:x + w])
            })

    return rectangles
```

**Some things that deserve highlighting:**

```
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
```

The THRESH_TOZERO_INV allows you to keep original pixel values with respect to the threshold. This allows you to get of the background lines while at the same time keeping the gray rectangle inside your green one.

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=25, minLineLength=1, maxLineGap=15)
```

I then use the hough transform (which finds the most probably lines in an image). Again this is a lot of hyperparameter tuning. Important has been to set the maxLineGap low, so the dashed lines are transferred to a line and not ignored.

```
# Apply morphological operations to enhance rectangles
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    dilated_mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=6)
    eroded_mask = cv2.erode(dilated_mask, kernel, iterations=5)
```

Last but not least the cv2.findContours function is pretty picky and only gets rectangles when they have completely closed contours meaning no gaps within the edges. To make sure I enhanced the mask with some morphological operations (basically expanding the lines to potentially close gaps and then eroding them again to make them thin). If you experience a little offset in the drawn lines, this is why.

Final Note: The dashed line results in two rectangles. If that is an issue you can look into cv2.RETR_TREE and the hierarchical structure of shapes within shapes and sort it out this way.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and explanatory response, as well as coaching on why the downvotes (I must admit I still don't fully understand that). Not only does it answer the question at hand but also gives guidance on how to deal with future problems that the challenge throws up.

Comment: I appreciate your response and am happy I could help. Enjoy your new skills.

Answer (score 0):

This code first converts the image to grayscale and then uses Canny edge detection to find edges. It then finds contours in the image and filters them by shape to identify rectangles. For each rectangle, it calculates its coordinates, width, height, and color. Finally, it prints the results and draws the rectangles on the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def find_rectangles(image):
  """
  Finds rectangles in an image and returns their coordinates and color.

  Args:
    image: The image to be processed.

  Returns:
    A list of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains the following keys:
      - x: The x-coordinate of the top-left corner of the rectangle.
      - y: The y-coordinate of the top-left corner of the rectangle.
      - w: The width of the rectangle.
      - h: The height of the rectangle.
      - color: The color of the rectangle as a tuple of (B, G, R) values.
  """

  # Convert the image to grayscale
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  

  # Find edges using Canny edge detection
  edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 60)

  # Find contours in the image
  contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  # Filter contours by shape
  rectangles = []
  for contour in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
      # Get the bounding box of the contour
      x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
      rectangles.append({
          "x": x,
          "y": y,
          "w": w,
          "h": h,
          "color": cv2.mean(image[y:y+h, x:x+w])
      })

  return rectangles

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread("image_path.jpg")

# Find rectangles
rectangles = find_rectangles(image)

# Print the results
for rectangle in rectangles:
  print(f"Rectangle: x={rectangle['x']}, y={rectangle['y']}, w={rectangle['w']}, h={rectangle['h']}, color={rectangle['color']}")

# Draw the rectangles on the image
for rectangle in rectangles:
  cv2.rectangle(image, (rectangle['x'], rectangle['y']), (rectangle['x'] + rectangle['w'], rectangle['y'] + rectangle['h']), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Display the image with rectangles
cv2.imshow("Image with Rectangles", cv2.resize(image, None , fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: This image I got]